# Contradiction on theorem of convergence for impoper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, improper-integrals

> **Theorem** 
> Let $|f(x)|<g(x)$ $\forall x \in [a,b)$. If integral $\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}$ converges then $\int_{a}^{b}{|f(x)|dx}$ also converges.

> **Proof**
> Since $\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}$ converges, then we could say that $\forall \varepsilon$ $\exists \delta\in (a,b)$, such that $\forall b_1,b_2\in(\delta,b)$ holds $\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{g(x)dx}\right|<\varepsilon$. Since $\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{g(x)dx}<\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{g(x)dx}\right|$, we can see that $\forall \varepsilon$ $\exists \delta\in (a,b)$, such that $\forall b_1,b_2\in(\delta,b)$ holds $\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{g(x)dx}<\varepsilon$.
> Functions $|f| and g$ are integrable for all segments $[a,x]\subset[a,b)$, thus they are integrable on $[a,b_2]$ and then also on $[b_1,b_2]\subseteq[a,b)$. Hence $\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{|f(x)|dx}\le\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{g(x)dx}<\varepsilon$. 
> So we can state that $\forall \varepsilon$ $\exists \delta\in (a,b)$, such that $\forall b_1,b_2\in(\delta,b)$ holds $\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{g(x)dx}\right|\le\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{|f(x)|dx}<\varepsilon$. Which means integral $\int_{a}^{b}{|f(x)|dx}$ converges.$\blacksquare$

So I've been told this theorem is incorrect (sadly, I forgot which textbook it is from). So I tried to find a contradiction by myself. A simple example would be [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function#:%7E:text=of%20the%20set%20of%20rational,mathematician%20Peter%20Gustav%20Lejeune%20Dirichlet.) on $[1,2)$ for example. So let's say \begin{equation}
f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } x \in [1,2)\cap\mathbb{Q}\\
        0 & \text{if } x \in [1,2)\setminus\mathbb{Q}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$g(x)=x$$
We obviously know that Dirichlet function is not integrable. We can see that $|f(x)|\le g(x)$, $\forall x\in[1,2)$. It's is easly show that $\int_{1}^{2}{g(x)dx}$ converges and from the theorem that $\int_{1}^{2}{|f(x)|dx}$ also converges, which is obviously incorrect.

Have I possibly missed something here?

What way could we modify this theorem so the statment "If integral $\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}$ converges then $\int_{a}^{b}{|f(x)|dx}$ also converges" is true? And how would that affect the proof?

Would something like the following modification be true?

> **Theorem**
> Let $|f(x)|<g(x)$ $\forall x \in [a,b)$. If $g$ and $f$ are integrable on segment $[a,\beta]\subset[a,b)$, then we could say that if integral $\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}$ converges then $\int_{a}^{b}{|f(x)|dx}$ also converges.

If this is true, would the proof be the same, as that of the original (wrong) theorem?

Comment: The theorem of your book was correct. The only point is that when it speaks of integrals form $a$ to $b$ which "converge", this implicitely assumes that the integrand is integrable on $[a,c]$ for every $c\in[a,b).$ (The "convergence" is the property that this integral from $a$ to $c$ has a finite limit when $c\to b$). This implicit assumption is not satisfied by the Dirichlet function.

Comment: @AnneBauval so essentially the theorem implicitly says the same thing as I've written in the modified version? On another note, it looks like using Dirichlet function was wrong example to begin with, but doesn't there exist some $f(x)$ such that $|f(x)|<g(x)$such that it's integrable on $[a,b)$, but it's integral doesn't converge? I'll try to find it.

Comment: Yes, your "modified version" is but an improvement of the formulation of your book, making the hypothesis more explicit. The proof is correct, so I wonder what you are now looking for.

Comment: Moreover, what did "integrable on $[a,b)$ but its integral does not converge" mean? Was your "integrable on $[a,b)$" an abreviation for "integrable on $[a,c]$ for every $c\in[a,b)$"? If so then, again: no, there does not exist such an $f,$ this would contradict the theorem.

Comment: @AnneBauval if you're correct then there doesn't exist such $f(x)$ for which there would be a contradiction to the book's theorem. But upon returning to your first comment, it doesn't make much sense to be fair. How can you make an assumption that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,c],\forall c\in [a,b)$ since it converges, if its convergence depends on convergence of integral of $g(x)$ on $[a,b)$? You're basically saying that if g(x) is integrable on $[a,c],\forall c\in [a,b)$, then that would mean f(x) is integrable on $[a,c],\forall c\in [a,b)$ which is Dirichlet function contradicts.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that in the statement of the theorem both functions $|f|,g$ are implicitely assumed to be integrable on $[a,c],\forall c\in [a,b)$, otherwise the "convergence" of their $\int_a^b$ (assumed for $g$ and derived for $|f|$) would make no sense.

Comment: @AnneBauval essentialy what you're saying is that assumption is left to the reader, because if you don't assume something that isn't written the theorem will be wrong, like in this case. To me this more looks like a case of lack of rigour in the theorem. Obviously such things that are essential to the correctness of the theorem should be defined explicitely, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Not "because the theorem will be wrong"  but simply because the statement would make no sense. And I still don't understand what kind of counterexample you said you will "try to find".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146818/discussion-between-bb-823-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: Just to add my two cents - it is an unfortunate but inevitable fact that theorems and their proof are occasionally stated sloppily. I've found that as I've encountered more advanced maths, the level of rigour has surprisingly fallen off a bit, since the reader is assumed to fill in the details. In this particular case, it's no big deal, since obviously to talk about $\int f$ we need to assume $f$ is (Riemann) (Lebesgue) integrable. Note that the Dirichlet function $f$ is *Lebesgue* integrable and it is indeed true that $\int|f|\le\int g$ where $g$ is the identity. The theorem is not wrong.

Comment: @FShrike could you give me an example of such theorems, so I could use it as an example for correctness of the theorem from the post. (Also we haven't worked with Lebesque integrals yet, so it needs to be Riemann integrable only).

Comment: I couldn't give you specific examples (especially not without 'throwing shade') but this is quite a well known phenomenon. Indeed there are various MO posts concerning incorrect theorems and their fixes, which is an extreme example; the theorem statement/proof is so sloppy that it's just false... It's good that you asked this question, though. Keep a keen and critical eye on what you read